# I want to fetch all data from a table and insert them in another table but only first row is inserting multiple time instead of all row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is the sql query.I cant figure out why one the first row in the tbl_cart is inserting multiple time in order_details table.i want to insert all row

```
$sql="SELECT * from tbl_cart";
                        $result = $this->db->conn->prepare($sql);
                        $result->execute();
                        $val= $result->fetch();
                      
                        

                        for ($i=0; $i < $result->rowCount(); $i++) { 
                            $sqlq="SELECT * from tbl_cart";
                            $result = $this->db->conn->prepare($sqlq);
                            $result->execute();
                            $valu= $result->fetch(); 

                            $proid = $valu['proid'];
                            $quantity = $valu['quantity'];
                            $price= $valu['price'];


                            $sql = "INSERT INTO   order_details (proid,quantity,price) values('$proid','$quantity','$price')";
                            $value = $this->db->conn->prepare($sql);
                            $data = $value->execute();
                        }
```

Comment: Why are you firing same select query again inside the for-loop ? You have already fetched the results from outer select query. Also, instead of doing this in php, you can solve this directly in mysql using `INSERT INTO . SELECT`

Comment: You can avoid for loop and run this command  `Insert into order_details (SELECT proid,quantity,price FROM tbl_cart)`

Answer (score -1):

Remove first four lines after for loop,it'll work

Comment: not working.its always inserting the first row multiple time not all row

Comment: Dont do query in loop, you can do this operation without using loop

Comment: Pls print $val before for loop